# New "Platform App Builder Certification" Exam vs "Salesforce Certified Administrator" Exam

Tags: certification, platform-app-builder, adm201, study-guide

I am preparing for my "Salesforce Certified Administrator" Exam myself using the Study guide and various study materials from Google/Internet.

Recently when I checked the study Guide for the "Platform App Builder Certification" most of the topics were already covered in "Salesforce Certified Administrator" but with different weight-age and except the topics under `"App Deployment 8%"` & `"Social 3%"`

- Is this "Salesforce Certified Administrator" preparation is enough to cover the "Platform App Builder Certification"
- Is there anyone who recently appeared for both exams to help me out to answer the above query, so that I can plan to attend the 2 exams?

Any help is appreciated & thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my Answer from SalesForce Success Community, I am sharing the link on this below
[New “Platform App Builder Certification” Exam vs “Salesforce Certified Administrator” Exam](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019N6TQAU)

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce Certifications are industry recognised qualifications that prove to employers or clients that you excel in a certain field within Salesforce. There are multiple routes of Salesforce Qualifications, **Administrator, Developer, Implementation Experts, App Builders, Architects, Pardot and Marketers**. Each of these have different levels of qualifications. However, most users of Salesforce will take a similar route and order of qualifications.

The Salesforce Certified Administrator is where most users start, this provides you with the basics of Salesforce, its standard and custom objects, automation and most importantly, it’s security model. From there, users will most likely specialise depending on their personal career goals and vocation.

It is a good idea to look into the Beginner Admin track first. This is because even if you are a developer looking to transition to Apex, there are so many declarative features on the Salesforce platform that you can leverage to do things without code. And the Admin track will give you an insight into what is possible to do via code and what isn't. Also, you will learn about the data object model, which will be so helpful to you.

Comment: It's understood & that's why I am planning for Admin first and thanks for your reply.. But my question was related specifically to the contents in the study guide of both Platform app certification and Admin. Are u able to help me in this